# Calculate cosine similarity and output without duplicates?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, similarity, cosine-similarity

I have the following vectors in my toy example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
            'a': [55, 2123, -19.3, 9, -8], 
            'b': [21, -0.1, 0.003, 4, 2.1]
        })
```

I have calculated similarity matrix (by excluding the id column).

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Calculate the pairwise cosine similarities 
S = cosine_similarity(data.drop('id', axis=1))

T  = S.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(T)
```

It returns me a matrix/dataframe with all options including self similarity and duplicates.
Is there any efficient method to calculate similarity without self similarities (vector is 100% similar to itself) and duplicates (vectors 1 and 2 has 89% similarity, I don't need vectors 2 and 1 similarity as it's the same).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found so far is to take the lower triangle under the diagonal:

```
[In] S[np.triu_indices_from(S, k=1)]

[Out] array([ 0.93420158, -0.93416293,  0.99856978, -0.81303909, -0.99999999,
    0.91379242, -0.96724292, -0.91374841,  0.96727042, -0.78074903])
```

What this does is take only those values that are under the 1 diagonal, so basically excluding the ones and the repeating values. This gives you a numpy array, too.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31588385)